# How to link boost library as dynamic library instead of static in vcpkg

Tags: dll, vcpkg, boost-serialization

I'm using VS 2019 with vcpkg and boost 1.81

I've created a Dynamic Link Library Project (c++) and I've added the boost serialization library headers.

when I set vcpkg to use static libraries it builds fine , however if i set the "Use static Libraries" to No then I get the following compiler errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2491   'boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<Archive>::insert': definition of dllimport function not allowed C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\boost\archive\impl\archive_serializer_map.ipp    41  
Error   C2491   'boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<Archive>::erase': definition of dllimport function not allowed  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\boost\archive\impl\archive_serializer_map.ipp    49  
Error   C2491   'boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<Archive,Elem,Tr>::basic_binary_iprimitive': definition of dllimport function not allowed   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\boost\archive\impl\basic_binary_iprimitive.ipp   146 
Error   C2491   'boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<Archive,Elem,Tr>::~basic_binary_iprimitive': definition of dllimport function not allowed  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\boost\archive\impl\basic_binary_iprimitive.ipp   170 
Error   C2491   'boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<Archive>::insert': definition of dllimport function not allowed C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\boost\archive\impl\archive_serializer_map.ipp    41  
Error   C2491   'boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<Archive>::erase': definition of dllimport function not allowed  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\boost\archive\impl\archive_serializer_map.ipp    49  
...[redacted]
```

what should i do to get it to build as a dynamic library?

UPDATE 2023/1/30
this issue happens only when adding the `portable_binary_iarchive` and `portable_binary_iarchive` files to the project. these files are not part of the standard boost library, however they are included in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a CMake project, add the following commond in your `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
```

Comment: I'm using vcpkg, that's not possbile